# How to return HTML from a AJAX call in Rails and fire the ajax:success event?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a form with `remote: true` set.

Here's the relevant coffeescript:

```
document.addEventListener 'turbolinks:load', ->
  $(document).on 'ajax:success', "form.new_carrier.specific", (event, data) ->
    console.log data
    console.log data.responseText
```

I have the following in the create method of my controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to_user }
  format.js do
    render partial: 'carriers/for_order', layout: false
  end
end
```

I want this to return an html partial, which it is correctly doing. But jQuery is expecting a JSON response, not HTML, so the `ajax:success` event never gets called (though I can use `ajax:complete`). How can I make the above return a response so that the `ajax:success` event will be called?

Comment: i don't understand, what do you mean jquery is expecting a json response?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon What I mean is that I get an error back when I use `ajax:error` on the same event. The error says `SyntaxError: unexpected token <' because it's getting HTML back, rather than the JSON I think it's expecting.

Comment: how is jquery expecting a json response?